# Upgrading from wp 3.2 to 3.4.2 breaks tinymce with buddy press

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, buddypress

I've gone through every possible solution I've found on the web and none work. Basically we have Wordpress with BuddyPress and we used bp-tinymce to get WYSIWYGs for the editable content areas.

Now wp_tiny_mce is deprecated I don't think we need the bp-tinymce plugin anymore (basically it tricked wordpress into thinking it should replace the buddypress content areas with wordpress tinymce areas) and just putting it inline with wp_editor() instead.

This seems (ie it places a styled wysiwyg into that area) but none of the necessary javascript is placed into the page so it doesn't act as one. I've tried:

```
add_filter('admin_head','ShowTinyMCE');
function ShowTinyMCE() {
    // conditions here
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-color' );
    wp_print_scripts('editor');
    if (function_exists('add_thickbox')) add_thickbox();
    wp_print_scripts('media-upload');
    if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) wp_tiny_mce();
    wp_admin_css();
    wp_enqueue_script('utils');
    do_action("admin_print_styles-post-php");
    do_action('admin_print_styles');
}
```

and other similar code into the functions.php of the theme but that function never gets called. I'm not sure if it's because of buddypress preventing it or not.

How can I get the required js into the page or am I doing this completely wrong?